# ¿Cómo pasar una variable con diferente valor por ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Necesito pasar el valor de una variable por medio de ajax con diferente valor.
Tengo una aplicación donde tengo un dropdownlist oculto posteriormente realizo una consulta con ajax a mi base de datos y dependiendo del resultado de la imagen que obtengo en mi ajax visualizo el dropdownlist.

Si el dropdownlist esta oculto el valor de la variable se pasara vacía pero si en la consulta del ajax la imagen es igual a la etapa 3 entonces el dropdownlist se hace visible y el valor de la variable sera igual a el valor seleccionado del dropdownlist.

Este es mi código de la consulta.

```js
function Consultar_datos() {

    var persona = $("[id*=ddlPersona]").val();
    var Sucursal = ""; // variable que se envia si el dropdownlist esta oculto
    Sucursal = $("[id*=ddlSucusal] option:selected").text(); // Cuando el dropdownlist esta visible se le envia el valor que se seleccione del dropdownlist. Ya no se le enviara una variable vacia.

    if (persona != 0) {

        var valores;
        var datafields = new Array();
        var columns = new Array();
        var columnsArray = [];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "frmPersona.aspx/Intervalo",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{id_persona:"' + persona + '",Sucursal:"' + Sucursal + '"}',
            async: false,

            success: function(data) {

                if (data != '') {

                    valores = JSON.parse(valores[0]);
                    var url_imagen = valores[1];
                    $("[id*=imgEtapas]").attr("src", url_imagen);

                    for (var i in valores[0]) {
                        datafields.push({ name: i, type: 'string' });
                        columns.push({ text: i, datafield: i, filtercondition: 'CONTAINS', align: 'center', minwidth: 100 });

                    }

                    for (var j = 1; j < columns.length; j++) {
                        columnsArray.push(columns[j]);

                    }
                                    // Cuando el resultado de imagen sea igual a etapa 3 se visualiza el dropdownlist y lo que se seleccione se pasa a la variable sucursal
                                      if (url_imagen === "Etapa3") 
                                      {                                        
                                         $("[id*=ddlSucusal]").css("visibility", "visible");
                                         $("[id*=ddlSucusal]").removeAttr("disabled");
                                      }             

                }

            },

            error: function(error) {
                alert(error.responseText);
                console.log(error.responseText);
                jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(Error.responseText);
                alert(error.respose.Text);
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Tu problema es que no se envía tu información correctamente? O que no recibes correctamente la información? El titulo confunde un poco

Comment: Hola @matahombres mi problema es como pasar el valor que se selecciona en el dropdownlist cuando este esta visible (se hace visible cuando el nombre de la imagen es igual a la etapa 3 que obtengo de la consulta ajax); ya que mientras el dropdownlist no se haga visible el valor de la variable Sucursal se pasa vacia.

Comment: Deberías de crear un evento cuando clickas al elemento del dropdownlist. O añadirle una clase de seleccionada y hacer un evento de cuando cambia el elemento y coja el valor de la clase seleccionada. Si puedes poner la estructura del dropdownlist estaría bien

Comment: No se deben incluir saludos ni gracias en las preguntas/respuestas. ref. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior. Por otro lado, Stack Snippet sólo debe usarse en código ejecutable; el código incluido no lo es (al hacer clic en el botón ejecutar no pasa nada).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

te sugiero que al invocar a la función **Consultar_datos** previamente verifiques el estado del **dropdown/select** y luego designes un valor correspondiente para este algo asi:

```js
function ConsultarValor(){
  //Selecciono el dropdown
  myDropDown = document.getElementById("myDropDown");
  //verifico el estado de mi dropdown none/block
  if( window.getComputedStyle(myDropDown).display === "none"){
    //asigno un valor en caso de estar oculto
    valorDropDown = null;
  }else{
    //obtengo el valor en caso de estrar mostrando el dropdown
    textoSeleecionado = myDropDown.options[myDropDown.selectedIndex].text;
  valorDropDown = myDropDown.value;
  }
  console.log('el valor es: '+valorDropDown);
}
```

```html
<select name="myDropDown" id="myDropDown" style="display:none">
  <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opcion 2</option>
</select>
<button onclick="ConsultarValor();">Obtener Valor</button>
```

**Explicación:**
Lo primero que debes hacer es obtener tu dropdown mediante un **ID**, una vez con esto verificamos el estado es decir si esta:

```
oculto = none
mostrando = block
```

en este caso lo valido si esta oculto(none) y por ende le designo un valor en mi caso le coloque null, pero puedes asignar el valor deseado y de la misma forma si esta mostrando el dropdown obtengo su valor seleccionado, para ello en cada **option** debes tener un value, pero si deseas obtener el valor por el texto mostrado en tu option solo debes cambiar por:

```
textoSeleecionado = myDropDown.options[myDropDown.selectedIndex].text;
```

ya con esto tendrias completada tu info para enviar por ajax.

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!